# generate iframe and get Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, iframe

Hello i have a question and  this one seems to be a bit of a challenge.

I have a link that creates an iframe and sends a few variables in the URL

i have this in a partial

```
   <a id="linkPreview" >More..</a>       


   $("#linkPreview").click(function(){
   createIframe();
   });

   function createIframe() {
   var user = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000);
   var frameURL ="http://www.website.com?var1=507&var2=508";
   var frame = $('<iframe></iframe>');
   frm.attr({
   'width': 204,
   'height': 355,
   'scrolling': 'yes',
   'src': frmURL
   });
   $('#iframe_window').append(frm);
   }
```

then inside the iframe I process the variables that i receive

The problem is that the iframe is created correctly only if i send a normal website without variables in the URL. If I send the variables I get this error

```
    Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

And my iframe gets this automatically

```
    element.style {
     display: none !important;
     visibility: hidden !important;
     opacity: 0 !important;
     background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
```

Any ideas why is this happening? or alternatives?

Thank you so much.

Comment: is `frm` defined elsewhere?  Don't you mean `frame` ? same thing with `frmURL`